RCD trip when current flow from Live to Earth
Can an RCD detect current flowing from live to earth assuming neutral is disconnected (or someone improperly connected earth to neutral terminal and nothing to the earth terminal)? From what I have understood of RCD working principles is that it detects an imbalance only.


Can an RCD detect current flowing from live to earth assuming neutral is disconnected

Yes.

From what I have understood of RCD working principles is that it detects an imbalance only.

There's still an imbalance when only the live wire is connected!

